# How to launch a command line binary from a Cocoa-Applescript application?

Tags: xcode, applescript

I want to create a simple GUI Cocoa-Applescript application for a command line binary called [gmsh](http://geuz.org/gmsh/). It can be launched with a number of arguments which I'd like to specify via the GUI. When it is launched it opens an X11 window.

Before I create a complex GUI I've created a simple interface with one textfield and one button. I want the textfield information to be one argument passed to the binary and when I click the button for the binary to launch with the argument.

I can make this work with a display alert, e.g. the alert displays the textfield input when the button is pressed. However, when I try to replace the display alert with a do shell script the application freezes and nothing happens.

I don't know where the appropriate place is to add the gmsh binary, so I've put it in Supporting Files.

This is my non-working AppDelegate.applscript,

```
script AppDelegate
property parent : class "NSObject"

property argOne : ""

on buttonClicked_(sender)
    -- display alert "Argument one is " & argOne
    do shell script "gmsh " & argOne
end buttonClicked_

on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened 
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
    -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
    return current application's NSTerminateNow
end applicationShouldTerminate_

end script
```

I don't need the app to remain open once the X11 app has launched as the Cocoa-Applescript is just a gui launcher.

Answer (score 0):

When performing a do shell script your GUI freezes as long as the shell script is running. When the program keeps freezing it means that your do shell script is hanging. The first thing I see is that I miss a space between the command and the arguments you send to do shell script. That's probably your first issue, it should be something like

```
  do shell script "gmsh " & argOne
```

When you want to keep the GUI responsive there are three options in AppleScriptObjC:

1. Run a shell command in the background
2. Use performSelectorInBackground_withObject_("NameOfHandler:", argument)
3. Create an NSTask

Comment: I corrected my typo but that doesn't help. I don't need the app to remain open once you click the button as it is just a GUI launcher for the binary which itself launches an X11 window.

Comment: Use: 'do shell script "gmsh " & quoted form of argOne & " &>/dev/null &"', This runs the shell command in the background.

Comment: I get command not found in the console output. How do I reference the binary located in the project supporting files folder?

Comment: If the file is copied successfully within the application it should be 'path to me' (which is path to your application bundle). To get to the file it should be 'posix path of ((path to me as text) & "Contents:Resources:gmsh")'